# Can't bind to 'mode' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, navbar, sidenav

Hi I don't know what to do with this

Here's the error

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mode' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'mode' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [ERROR ->][mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    "): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@3:6
Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'opened' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("et$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [ERROR ->][opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@4:6
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    [ERROR ->]<mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@5:4
'mat-nav-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-nav-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-nav-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    [ERROR ->]<mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@6:4
'mat-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialo"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@1:2
'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        [ERROR ->]<mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>tester</span>"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@20:8
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    [ERROR ->]<mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@13:4
'mat-sidenav-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@12:2
'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewp"): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidenavComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20605)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26171)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26158)
    at compiler.js:26101
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26101)
    at compiler.js:26011
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2421)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
```

My structure is like this

[image]

1. Sidenav is generated by `@angular/material:material-nav --name=sidenav`
2. imports are moved from **app.module.ts** to **app.material.module.ts**
   where
   **MatToolbarModule,
   MatButtonModule,
   MatSidenavModule,
   MatIconModule,
   MatListModule**
   are included.
3. AdminLayoutComponent and AuthLayoutComponent are the only components here
4. material module is

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: have you imported your `MaterialModule` in `AppModule`?

Comment: yes it is imported

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a similar problem.  I had all the modules set up properly but the HTML just couldn't find the materials sidenav.

In the end it turned out that I had accidently removed AppComponent from the declarations part of app.module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatSidenavModule,
      ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I wasn't 'using it'; I was only using the HTML part of the component ... so I must have deleted the declaration to be tidy.  Turns out that the module uses this declaration to know who gets it's imported information and that the HTML is as much a part of the component as the javascript and css parts.

Hopefully this will help someone else; I suspect the original poster is long gone.

Comment: I do have AppComponent in the declarations part of app.module.ts, but I can't get rid of the problem. I know it's been 2 years from your answer, but does anyone have an idea how to solve this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is evidence that you have failed to import `MatSidenavModule` properly in the module where you are attempting to use it. The error indicates that the failure occurs in `ComponentsModule` so that is where the import is missing. You need to import `MaterialModule` or `MatSidenavModule` into `ComponentsModule`.